# extjs4 - get itemselector label value

Tags: extjs4

Looking at the extjs4 documentation for the itemselector, theres a method **getValue()** that returns the valueField on an array, i would like to know if there is a method that gets the displayField of the value.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing. You would need to write your own, or look up item by it's value and get displayField from it. Considering your last question I think you really need to extend standard ItemSelector and have your own ItemSelectorEx.

Comment: at least there is a way to get the displayField for a specific value? i could work with that

Comment: No. What I meant is - you have store with data which ItemSelector uses. You get the values from the ItemSelector. Then you do a lookup in your store and get full models of data selected in the ItemSelector. At that point you can get whatever was displayed or anything else.

Comment: When we needed similar functionality in our product I ended up writing similar component with two lists and ->, <- buttons. But we need to have real-time database updates as well, so when user moves item from store to selected store - we updated server right away.

Comment: I have other places where i use grids and -> and <- buttons, but it felt much more cleaner with the itemselector, also i got the other problem solved, i just need to get the value label and its all done

Comment: also, i use the itemselector in other places too, but this is the first time i need to use ral-time changes, hence the problems im ahving

Comment: Can you type the code line to manually get the displayField as you said in the answer?

Comment: i find the answer myself, but i will upvote your ayway since it is actually correct